# How to count the orders of one product?

Tags: laravel

I have `products` , `orders` and third pivot table `product_order`(product_id , order_id), I need to count the orders of the product based on `created_at`

my shut:

```
public function product_chart(Product $product)
{
        $orders = $product->whereHas('orders', function ($query)  {
                    $query->whereMonth('created_at', '04');
                })->count();
    dd($orders);
}
```

The output gives the number of products :(

of course, I have a relation in a product called (orders) and in Order called (products)

So I need to count the orders of the product based on the created_at of order!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are counting the products.

You can simply do this:

```
$ordersCount = $product->orders()->count();
```

But since you are applying some conditions, you need to append the where clause:

```
$ordersCount = $product->orders()->whereMonth('created_at', '04')->count();
```

Also there's a simpler way doing it according to [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models):

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

$posts = App\Post::withCount(['votes', 'comments' => function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
}])->get();

echo $posts[0]->votes_count;
echo $posts[0]->comments_count;
```

Comment: thanks worked, but what if I need to count the total price of the product in these orders? what is the idea pls?  again based on created_at like day or year